# Jupyer Notebook not hiding cells even with the hide-input tag

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I realize there are plenty of questions about hiding Jupyter Notebook cells, but even following all the instructions I can find, Jupyter still refuses to hide the cell.

I've added the 'hide-input' tag to my cell, and this is what the metadata looks like:

```
{
  "trusted": true,
  "tags": [
    "hide-input"
  ]
}
```

Is there some sort of trigger to implement the tag other than running the cell itself? Why won't it hide the input?

My version is 6.0.3, and as far as I can tell tags were implemented in the Version 5 range. I can't see why it isn't working for me.

Comment: You probable should read through some of the last few posts in [the thread 'Difficulty Editing Metadata Tags to Hide Cell Inputs and Outputs' here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/difficulty-editing-metadata-tags-to-hide-cell-inputs-and-outputs/14973/4?u=fomightez). The last one gives more current insight into what works and doesn't. Importantly, 6.0.3 is **really outdated**. Unless you aren't specifying your version of Jupyter interface , old Jupyter Notebook, vs newer NbClassic, etc., as well there.

Answer (score 0):

Right, so I figured it out - I guess I should have been looking into how to "collapse" a cell rather than hide it, because the solution is simply to click the blue bar on the left of the cell. Why that's not the first line of any answer or article about hiding cells, I'm not sure, but that's that I suppose.

Comment: Glad you sorted what you are looking for. You sort of focused on the hiding and tag stuff. For example, read your title out of context. Sometimes it is best to ask what you are trying to do and not how you think it should be done, like creating [an XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). Aside from that minor comment, any specific documentation out there in the Jupyter world that could be improved? I'll add that [I had this thorough answer here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/can-i-collapse-fold-cells-in-the-exported-html-file-from-a-notebook/8579/6?u=fomightez).